# Variable previousValue is returning a NullReferenceException: Object not set to an instance of object

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

This code has an error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

```
IEnumerator WinLog_big_road(){

string[] historyValue = new string[] { };

NetworkManager.Instance.WebSocketServer.OnCallBack_SC_WEBSOCKET_GametableHistory += CallBack_CS_WEBSOCKET_GametableHistory;

historyValue = PlayInfo.Instance.HistoryValue;

    foreach (var previousValue in historyValue)
    {
         if (previousValue.Contains(playerwinnopairboth))
         {
              o.GetComponent<UISprite>().spriteName = "layout_player_bigline-01";
              NGUITools.SetActive(o, true);
          }
    }
}

private void CallBack_CS_WEBSOCKET_GametableHistory(bool success, Int32 gametable_no, Int32 year, Int32 month, Int32 day, Int32 shoe_no, gametable_history_list list)
{
    string[] newString = new string[4];
    string[] newChars = new string[4];

    if (gametable_no == 1)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < PlayInfo.Instance.gametable_history_list.Count; i++)
        {
            newString[0] += PlayInfo.Instance.gametable_history_list[i].r;
            newString[0] += ",";
        }
        newChars[0] = newString[0].Split(',').ToString();
    }
   //upto gametable 4
   PlayInfo.Instance.History = newChars;
}
```

On my `PlayInfo.Instance.History` here's what it looks like

```
private string[] historyvalue;
public string[] HistoryValue
{
    get { return historyvalue; }
    set { historyvalue = value; }

}
```

I tried checking my arrays if null using my extension method

```
 public static bool IsNullOrEmpty(Array array)
{
    return (array == null || array.Length == 0);
}
```

So i tried my `PlayInfo.Instance.History` if it was `null` but it was not null. Then also tried my `historyValue` and it was not `null`.

Now it's pointing me here `foreach(var previousValue in HistoryValue)` that my `previousValue` is null.

I proved that by Debugging `if(previousValue == null)` and yes it was a null.

Could someone please explain why is it null. Am i not getting the value of `PlayInfo.Instance.HistoryValue` then pass it to `historyValue`.

Comment: Looks like `historyValue` is being populated with null values. You need to debug the check from where the null is injected in the array.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya does passing the value of string array doesn't work like this ? `PlayInfo.Instance.HistoryValue = newChar`

Comment: your code says `PlayInfo.Instance.History = newChar`. but you are trying to iterate thru `PlayInfo.Instance.HistoryValue`. So `PlayInfo.Instance.HistoryValue` and `PlayInfo.Instance.History` are the same? or is it typo in the question? Did you debug the code and checked if `CallBack_CS_WEBSOCKET_GametableHistory` code is executing or not?

Comment: I'm using a delegate sir . So I'm executing it on a `IEnumerator`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing it on the `IEnumerator` function i just do it on my `CallBack_CS_WEBSOCKET_GametableHistory` function

```
IEnumerator WinLog_big_road(){
NetworkManager.Instance.WebSocketServer.OnCallBack_SC_WEBSOCKET_GametableHistory += CallBack_CS_WEBSOCKET_GametableHistory;
}
```

then on my `CallBack_CS_WEBSOCKET_GametableHistory` function

```
private void CallBack_CS_WEBSOCKET_GametableHistory(bool success, Int32 gametable_no, Int32 year, Int32 month, Int32 day, Int32 shoe_no, gametable_history_list list)
{
string[] newString = new string[4];

   if (gametable_no == 1)
   {
       for (int i = 0; i < PlayInfo.Instance.gametable_history_list.Count; i++)
       {
           newString[0] += PlayInfo.Instance.gametable_history_list[i].r;
           newString[0] += ",";
       }
       string[] newChars = newString[0].Split(',').ToString();
       DeleteChildrens(pos_big_road[0]);
       foreach (string previousValue in newChars)
       {
            GameObject o = Instantiate(prefab_big_road[0]) as GameObject;
            o.transform.SetParent(pos_big_road[0]);
            o.transform.localScale = Vector3.one;
            o.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(2.0f, -5.0f, 0f);
       }
    }
}
```

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see "tzPlayInfo" anywhere in the code you provided. But it is possible for previousValue to be null if PlayInfo.Instance.History has any null values in it before setting historyValue. From the code provided I don't see where PlayInfo.Instance.History would be populated.

I wonder if there is some confusion around what this line does.

```
NetworkManager.Instance.WebSocketServer.OnCallBack_SC_WEBSOCKET_GametableHistory += CallBack_CS_WEBSOCKET_GametableHistory;
```

This is adding the CallBack_CS_WEBSOCKET_GametableHistory as an Event Handler but not calling that function to execute.

Comment: It was a `typo` it is only `PlayInfo`

Comment: What do you mean sir "This is adding the CallBack_CS_WEBSOCKET_GametableHistory as an Event Handler but not calling that function to execute."

Comment: It looks like you are trying to set PlayInfo.Instance.History equal to newChars in the CallBack_CS_WEBSOCKET_GametableHistory function. But there is no guarantee that this code will be executed before you assign historyValue = PlayInfo.Instance.HistoryValue;

Comment: in the CallBack_CS_WEBSOCKET_GametableHistory function the PlayInfo.Instance.HistoryValue = newChars is not a `null` the problem is that on my `IENumerator` function after `NetworkManager.Instance.WebSocketServer.OnCallBack_SC_WEBSOCKET_GametableHistory +=CallBack_CS_WEBSOCKET_GametableHistory;` is executed i declared a string array to pass the value of `PlayInfo.Instance.HistoryValue` but its not successfull

Comment: If the error is "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" and it is happening at "foreach(var previousValue in HistoryValue)" That means that the historyValue array contains a null object for at least one of its values. Since historyValue is assigned equal to PlayInfo.Instance.HistoryValue that means that the PlayInfo.Instance.HistoryValue array contains at least one null.

Comment: Could you help me fix it sir ethan?

Comment: I'd love to, can you post the code that uses the WinLog_big_road and the code that is calling NetworkManager.Instance.WebSocketServer.OnCallBack_SC_WEBSOCKET_GametableHistory